# file upload - django admin - OSError - no such file or directory

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save image to imagefield of a model thru admin page but i am getting this error message:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

this is my model

```
def custom_path_tc(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['topiccenter',instance.title,filename])

class TopicCenter(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=custom_path_tc,default='',blank=True,null=True)
```

and this is my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import TopicCenter

admin.site.register(Person)
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

under `media` folder the new folder will be created during upload but on the way i am getting this error message, what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using path `'topiccenter`/`instance.title`/`filename'` to store the file, you need to create `'tocpiccenter/instance.title`' directory if it does not exists.

Do that in `custom_path_tc()` function.

Comment: interesting... if i upload thru admin, the folders wont be created, i have to create them on the way... thanks for the tip